# Jstree from oracle DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, jstree

I have three different tables viz, Group, Line, and item in an Oracle database. I need to fetch groupname, Grouplinename and itemname from the tables respectively and want to populate a jstree.

It would be three level in jstree Groupname has Grouplinename inside and grouplinename has itemname inside. I m using C#, ASP.Net and jQuery. Please I need a brief explanation or complete code.

Answer (score 0):

brief explanation:

- start a web application or web site project
- write SQL returning a flattened set of tree items
- write C# to build the tree structure as C# dictionaries (fetching records from the DB)
- create ASP web page serving the result as JSON data (JavaScriptSerializer)
- create a static .html file containing the jstree and jquery code